# How to configure `I18n Ally` VsCode plugin to read my locals from one single file?

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, vue-i18n, i18n-ally

I'm using [`vue-i18n`](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/) package to translate my Vue project and want to use ["I18n Ally"](https://github.com/antfu/i18n-ally/wiki/FAQ) vs code extention to manage translations. The default folder structure for this extension is this:

```
  locales         # i18n, langs, locale are also acceptable
  ├── en.json
  ├── de-DE.json
  ├── zh-CN.yml   # YAML
  ├── zh-TW.ts    # You can mix different formats
  ├── ...
  └── <country-code>.json
```

But I have one single translation file with this format:

```js
{
 "en": {
    "users": {
      "title": "Users list",
      "menu": {
        "show_users": "Display users",
        "hands_down": "Hands down",
        "unblock_all": "Unblock all"
      },
...
```

And I cannot configure the extension to read this configuration.

Answer (score 7):

Author of i18n Ally here. Currently, we don't support the locale code as top-level keys in json files. I'd suggest using the following format in dedicated files for each locale, which will also get better support over other i18n tools.

```json
{
   "users": {
      "title": "Users list",
      "menu": {
        "show_users": "Display users",
        "hands_down": "Hands down",
        "unblock_all": "Unblock all"
      },
...
```

This should be a better practice as your application grows as well. Thanks for the understanding and hope you enjoy the extension.